# How to let python class metod inherit library functions?

Tags: python, matplotlib, inheritance

Part of a class I am writing is a wrapper for plotting with matplotlib.

however, I want my wrapper to still be able to pass all plotting options.

Example:

```py
import matplotlib as plt
import numpy as np

class parentclass():
   def __init__(self):
       #functions to read some data
       data=np.arange(100)

   def plotaline(self,customargument1,customargument2,**kwargs):
       cmin=customargument1*2
       cmax=customargument2*4
       #these are just for the sake of having other arguments

       plt.plot(self.data,vmin=cmin,vmax=vmax,**kwargs)

# expected: 
mydata=parentclass()
#plots a data line with red crosses as it takes the args that usually would go into plt.plot()
mydata.plotaline(0,1,'r-+')
```

I know something is missing. I need a way to pass the "plot" method from the plt library to my class method.
maybe it's some logic i am missing here, granted I probably do not know enough about inheritance.

Help would be much appreciated.

Comment: Where is your child class? There is no inheritance happening here. Also what is your actual output and what is your desired output?

Comment: Maybe this is worded a bit weird.  There is not really a child class, I want the method "plotaline" to inherit the behaviour of "plt.plot()"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add `*args` and `**kwargs` to include both optional positional arguments and keyword arguments.

```
def plotaline(self,customargument1,customargument2, *args, **kwargs):
       cmin=customargument1*2
       cmax=customargument2*4
       #these are just for the sake of having other arguments

       plt.plot(self.data,vmin=cmin,vmax=vmax, *args, **kwargs)
```

Comment: That would make the arguments passable I think, but stuff like docstring and so on wouldn't appear, right?

Comment: If you want docstring set it manually. `plotaline.__doc__ = plt.plot.__doc__`